# Css button:focus

Tags: html, css, input

I want to add focus to my buttons so when someone clicks on one, it'll change color
I tried `.button:focus` but nothing happens

Here's my snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;

}

.button {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:none;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#333;
  color: grey;
  height:50px;
  width:134px; 
  font-variant:small-caps;
}

.button:hover {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:none;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#333;
  color: #FF0000;
  height:50pxpx;
  width:134px; 
  text-decoration:none;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  background-color: #111;
}

.button:focus {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<form action='' method="POST">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Login In"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="prodcuts" class="button" value="Products"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="question" class="button" value="Question"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: You should start with valid HTML. You cannot put an `input` inside an `a`.

Comment: **Quick Tip**: You can use [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check if your HTML is valid.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Clicking on one of the buttons in your live demo causes the focus styling to apply to it (then the form submits and a new page is loaded).

Answer (score 4):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9838274385f08a1729905c5274944518

<kbd>[`:focus`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/)</kbd> only works on `input[type=text]` and `textarea` elements, but also works on other elements like div's if they have the [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute.

So focus for a `input[type=submit]`, `input[type=button]`, or button element will not work.

Instead use <kbd>[`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)</kbd>

**Quick Tip**: You can use [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check if your HTML is valid.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #333;
  color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 134px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.button:hover {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 134px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  background: #111;
}

.button:active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<form action='' method="POST">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Login In"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="prodcuts" class="button" value="Products"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="question" class="button" value="Question"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: ":focus only works on input[type=text] and textarea elements" — That simply isn't true. All form controls (as well as links) are focusable by default.